# Detect whether email is sent or not + Blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I am facing a little problem with `Transport.send(msg)` function of Blackberry API. In my application I need to send a sound file. But I want to know what happens if the device loses connectivity in middle of sending the email.

I tried to enclose the `Transport.send(msg)` call within try catch block but it never throws exception even if I manually turn off the Wi-Fi from the device while the file is being sent. If by any chance email could not be sent I want to show the user a dialog saying that email could not be sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can catch `SendFailedException` which is thrown when a message cannot be sent.

You can monitor the messages by calling `getStatus()` on a message which should return you the values given [here](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/blackberry/api/mail/Message.Status.html)